# Structured Streaming not writing to HDFS in cluster mode

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I am using structured streaming. The application successfully writes to HDFS when I have set the master to local when building the sparksession and deploying it in client mode when using spark-submit.

when I comment master(local) and in spark-submit when I deploy mode as cluster, it doesnt write to HDFS. I am trying to run in YARN and deploy mode as cluster. Do I need to specify spark.yarn.keytab as specified below: Appreciate any inputs.

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder      
      .master("local[*]")
      .config("spark.yarn.keytab", "/home/svcid/svcid.keytab")
      .config("spark.yarn.principal", "svc@domain.com")
      .appName("parsing-test")
      .enableHiveSupport()
      .getOrCreate()
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the Spark documentation for Security on [Using a Keytab](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/security.html#using-a-keytab) you need to provide Spark with a principal and keytab (e.g. using `spark-submit` with `--principal` and `--keytab` parameters:

> "By providing Spark with a principal and keytab (e.g. using `spark-submit` with `--principal` and `--keytab` parameters), the application will maintain a valid Kerberos login that can be used to retrieve delegation tokens indefinitely.

> Note that when using a keytab in cluster mode, it will be copied over to the machine running the Spark driver. In the case of YARN, this means using HDFS as a staging area for the keytab, so it’s strongly recommended that both YARN and HDFS be secured with encryption, at least."

Also, do not just comment out `master(local)` in your code but rather replace it with `master("yarn")` if you are planning to run the application on YARN.

If this is still not helping, please share your logs and the error message you are getting.

Comment: Yes I added principal and keytab into spark submit commands like below. spark2-submit --queue default --jars spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.3.0.jar --class com.xxx.App --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --keytab /home/svchdcid/svchdcid.keytab --principal svchdcid@DOMAIN.COM file.jar.   Same program works fine when I use master(local) in sparksession and in spark-submit if I have deploy mode as client.  when I commented master(local) in spark session and changed deploy mode to cluster, it doesnt write the data to HDFS.